# Nodejs-cron for logging

Tags: node.js, cron

Hi I'm trying to make a cronjob for From this month on, they will work at 10.00 pm on the first day of each month.
My try is ( i created this from cron-expression-generator )

```
var job = new CronJob('0 0 12 1 1/1 ? *', function() {

  let UserCount=0;
  User.count({}, function( err, count){    
   
      console.log(count);
 
  });

}, null, true, ' ..somewhere_in_world..');
job.start();
```

But it gives error

```
throw new Error('Too many fields');
```

Also it works fine as every second like

```
var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
```

How can I make it
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```html
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                   7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * * <command to execute>
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

`0 22 1 * *` this will run at 10:00pm on the first of every month

Comment: OP wanted 10 pm

Comment: Thank you so much it works, i tyred as" 5 22 7 * *" and console log worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is already answered, just adding cool website link to help with it in future

https://crontab.guru/